# When to use functional setState

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been learning React over the past few days, looking at a few tutorials and explanations regarding the different ways in which you can write different elements. However there is one I have been most curious about - the `setState` function to update/override the `state` properties of a component.

For example, imagine I have a class with the following:

```
class Photos extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        state = {
            pictures: []
        }
    }

   componentDidMount() {
      // This is where the fetch and setState will occur (see below)
   }

    render() {
       return {
          <div className="container">
             {this.state.pictures}
          </div>
       }
    }
}
```

This example sees me fetch images from an API.

Given that I have performed my fetch, map and return for this function - I will then update the `pictures: []` state array with the results gained in the API call.

My question stems from the differing methods I have seen regarding how to update/override the pictures state property.

I have seen it written in 2 varying ways:

**1)** *This seems to be a very simple and easy to read method*

`this.setState({pictures: pics})`

**2)** *This is more complex but I have see it described as a more safe method*

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   pictures: prevState.pictures.concat(pics)
}))
```

Could somebody please explain the merits of using either? I want to be consistent with code in the future, dealing with props and states etc, so the most versatile method would of course be preferred.

Comment: Those two pieces of code are not equivalent - version 1 sets `state.pictures` to `pics`, whereas version 2 sets `state.pictures` to the previous `state.pictures` with `pics` appended to the end.

Comment: @JoeClay, no it isn't since its not a callback but an updater function to setState

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: Whoops, yeah, you're right. Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First things first, in your case the two syntaxes are entirely different, what you might be looking for is the difference between

```
this.setState({pictures: this.state.picture.concat(pics)})
```

and

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   pictures: prevState.pictures.concat(pics)
}))
```

To understand why the second method is a preferred one,you need to understand what React does with `setState()` internally.

React will first merge the object you passed to `setState()` into the current state. Then it will start that reconciliation thing. Because of the calling `setState()` might not immediately update your state.

React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for better performance.

Consider the simple case, to understand this, in your function you might call `setState()` more than once like:

```
myFunction = () => {

   ...
   this.setState({pictures: this.state.picture.concat(pics1)})
   this.setState({pictures: this.state.picture.concat(pics1)})
   this.setState({pictures: this.state.picture.concat(pics1)})

   ...
}
```

which isn't a valid use case in a simple app but as the app gets complex, multiple `setState()` calls may be happening from multiple places, doing the same thing.

So now to perform an efficient update, React does the batching thing by extracting all the objects passed to each `setState()` call, merges them together to form a single object, then uses that single object to do `setState()`. According to the `setState()` documentation:

> This form of `setState()` is also asynchronous, and multiple calls during the same cycle may be batched together. For example, if you attempt to increment an item quantity more than once in the same cycle, that will result in the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Object.assign(
>   previousState,
>   {quantity: state.quantity + 1},
>   {quantity: state.quantity + 1},
>   ...
> )
> ```
>
> Subsequent calls will override values from previous calls in the same cycle, so the quantity will only be incremented once. If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead:
>
> ```
> this.setState((state) => {
>   return {quantity: state.quantity + 1};
> });
> ```
>
> For more detail, see:
>
> - [State and Lifecycle guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
> - [In depth: When and why are `setState()` calls batched?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610973/458193)
> - [In depth: Why isn’t `this.state` updated immediately?](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710)
>
> — [`setState()` - Other APIs - React.Component – React](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

So if any of the objects contains the same key, the value of the key of the last object with same key is stored. And hence the update only happens once with the last value.

**[Demo Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/212nolk1wr)**

Comment: for the demo. A demo worth's a thousand words.

Answer (score 17):

**TL;DR:** Functional `setState` is mainly helpful to expect correct state update when multiple `setState`s are triggered in a short interval of time where as conventional `setState` does reconciliation and could lead to unexpected state.

Please check this wonderful article on [**Functional setState**](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b) to get a clear understanding

And here is the [**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/functional-setstate?file=index.js)

Firstly, you are trying to do different things in each of your cases, you are assigning pics in one and concatenating pics in another.

Lets say this.state.pictures contain `[1, 2, 3]` and pics contain `[4, 5, 6]`

`this.setState({pictures: pics})`

In the above case this.state.pictures will contain the pics i.e `this.state.pictures = [4, 5, 6]`

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   pictures: prevState.pictures.concat(pics)
}))
```

Whereas in the above snippet, this.state.pictures will contain the previous pictures + pics i.e `this.state.pictures = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Either way you can tweak it to meet your API needs, if it's like a paginated response the you are better off concatenating the results on each request, else if you get the whole array each time just assign the whole array.

**Conventional setState VS Functional setState**

Now, your question mainly is probably whether to use `setState` with an object or with a function.

People use both of them for different reasons, now the functional `setState` is said to be safe because `React` does something called a reconciliation process where in it merges multiple objects inside `setState` when triggered frequently or concurrently and applies the changes in one shot, kind of like a batch process. This could potentially lead to some unexpected results in scenarios like below.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
increaseScoreBy3 () {
 this.setState({score : this.state.score + 1});
 this.setState({score : this.state.score + 1});
 this.setState({score : this.state.score + 1});
}
```

As you would expect the score to be incremented by 3 but what React does is merge all the objects and update the score only once i.e incrementing it by 1

This is one of the cases where functional callback shines because reconciliation does not happen on functions and executing the below code will do things as expected i.e update score by 3

```
increaseScoreBy3 () {
 this.setState(prevState => ({ score: prevState.score + 1 }));
 this.setState(prevState => ({ score: prevState.score + 1 }));
 this.setState(prevState => ({ score: prevState.score + 1 }));
}
```

Comment: But if I had only single setState call inside increaseScoreBy3, `this.setState({score : this.state.score + 1})` should work as expected? And in such a case, using the functional callback will not make any difference I believe.

Comment: Right, in that case, your assumption is true. however, instead of deciding each time what form of setState to use, we can just opt for less error prone functional approach and eliminate this decision fatigue.

Comment: So all signs point to using function setState all the time. I don't want to deal with down the road bugs, who does? But then, at what cost? I imagine batching set states helps with performance. Are there any good rules to follow about when to use one vs the other?

Comment: `where functional callback shines because reconciliation does not happen on functions and executing the below code will do things as expected` can you please explain more? @Nandu

Comment: I Agree with @CrhistianRamirez , anyone knows the performance difference between the two?

Answer (score 4):

A Quick answer:

**Always use functional form of setState().**

```
this.setState((state, props)=>({
    someValue: state.somevalue + 1
}));
```

This approach is less error-prone and helps to eliminate some very hard-to-find bugs. Even if react batches multiple such updates, each update is separate function call and subsequent updates will not cause some of these updates to be lost.

The other approach

```
this.setState({
someValue: state.somevalue + 1
});
```

If repeated frequently, **might cause some of the updates to be lost**, since React batches such frequent updates.

Comment: Always use functional form of setState().

This is bad advice. Write better code in such a way that you don't need to update state many times.

Comment: @AmitJS94 that advice is for newbies. If you know what you are doing, use the other general form.