# State not updating for component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a tapper component where everytime a user clicks on the button the number inside of the component goes up one.

[image]

The tapper component gets an initial value from a local json file. When the tapper is pressed however it fired the onClick function but doesn't update the state so the number doesn't go up! I'm new to react so I don't know if I'm approching this problem incorrectly.

My intent in the future is for the button to update the json value so that anyone people who visit the page in the future can hit it and make the number go up.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Icon, Label} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import tapperValue from './tappervalue.json';

    export default class TapperOutput extends Component {

      constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
          tapperValue: tapperValue.tapperValue
        }
      }

      handleClick = () => {
        console.log('Before the conversion ' + this.state.tapperValue);
        const taps = this.state.tapperValue + 1;
        this.setState = ({tapperValue: taps});
        console.log('After the conversion ' + this.state.tapperValue);
      }

      render() {

        return (
        <Label onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Icon name='hand paper'/> {this.state.tapperValue}
        </Label>);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** of all, setState is a function and you don't need an assignment operator with it.

**Second:** `setState` is `async` and hence the update isn't visible immediately, so you need to log the value in setState callback. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately/41278440#41278440) for more details

**Third**: when you are updating the current state based on the previous one, its better to use the updater function syntax provide by setState. Check this answer on [`when to use Updater function with setState`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209452/when-to-use-updater-function-with-setstate/48209870#48209870)

Simply write

```
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Before the conversion ' + this.state.tapperValue);
    this.setState(prevState => ({tapperValue: prevState.tapperValue + 1}), () => {
        console.log('After the conversion ' + this.state.tapperValue);
    });

  }
```

Comment: Also by the way gave the other answer a read very interesting that clears up a lot of questions I had about updating states!

Comment: Can you clarify your last comment, I did not understand

Comment: Oh I was just saying that I gave the "When to use Updater function with setState" question/answer a read and it clarified many things I was wondering about state and how it works!