# change setState from user Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm fairly new to React and experimenting with React. I am making a set of cubes that when a user clicks, alternate between colors.

To learn more about setState, I added an input so that when the user enters a color, the color of the cubes changes. The problem is the color of the cube changes, but when I click on the cube it goes back to the default one. I want the cubes to change the colors that are inputted by the user.

What have I tried?
I tried changing pink in `this.setState({color: 'pink'})` to setColor(), but it doesn't work. I looked around here, but couldn't find anything that would answer my question.

I've created the issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mpbdcf).

```
class TicTacToe extends Component {

  state = {
    color: 'black',
    colors: 'white',
    count: 0
  }

  changeColor(c){
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
    if(this.state.count % 2 === 0){
      this.setState({color: 'pink'})
      this.setState({colors: 'grey'})
    } else if (this.state.count % 2 !== 0){
      this.setState({color: 'grey'})
      this.setState({colors: 'pink'})
    }
  }

  setColor(color){
    return this.setState({color: color})
  }

  setColors(color){
    this.setState({colors: color})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="main">
          <div className="inputFields">
              <span> Color One:
                <input value={this.state.color}
                       onChange={(e)=> this.setColor(e.target.value)} /> </span>
              <br /><br />

              <span> Color Two:
                <input value={this.state.colors}
                        onChange={(e)=> this.setColors(e.target.value)} /> </span>
          </div>
          <div onClick= {(c)=> this.changeColor()}>
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}}></div>
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors}}></div>
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}}></div>
            <br />
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors}}></div>
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}}></div>
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors}}></div>
            <br />
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}}></div>
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors}}></div>
            <div className='square' style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}}></div>
          </div>
            <span> This is the count: {this.state.count} </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TicTacToe;
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what the cause of your problem was, but here's my solution: https://react-i8rer3.stackblitz.io. All the best ✌️

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the problem, but I would try passing a function as the first argument of separate. Take a look at https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b

Comment: Ahh wait the problem was the `changeColor()` `function`. The values were set `Strings` rather than `dynamic variables` based on `state`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes back to the default `onClick`, because `onClick` you are manually setting the `colors`, Also you don't need a count variable to alternate between `colors`. The count state is also not used properly. All you need is to use functional setState and implement `changeColor` like

```
changeColor(c){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      color: prevState.colors,
      colors: prevState.color
    }))
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q31xdv?file=index.js)**

Check **[When to use functional setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209452/when-to-use-functional-setstate/48209870#48209870)**

Check [**setState doesn't update the state immediately**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately/41278440#41278440)

Comment: Thanks! How would you suggest I do the count state? Using functional setState?

Comment: Why do you want to count state

Comment: I originally started this project to make tic tac toe, but it was too hard so I deviated. On every odd click, I wanted a cross sign and on every even click, I wanted a checkmark. So I wanted to count the clicks.

Comment: Sure, you must use functional setState for count too. Check  the link in my answer on when to use functional setState