# Take an action on props change in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to use current props and previous props value in my React component.
So i did it like this

```
state = {
    current: null,
    previous: null,
};

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.amount !== this.state.current) {
        this.setState({previous: this.state.current, current: nextProps.amount});
    }
}

...

render() {
    const {previous, current} = this.state;

    return (
        ...
        <CountUp className="counter" start={previous} end={current} duration={1}/>
        ...
    )
}
```

It works fine, but is it good React practise to do it like this? Are there others "good" ways to do it?

Comment: `setState(prevState)` is provided by React along with `props` both of which are optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of `v16.2.0`, `componentWillReceiveProps` is the right place to update state, based on prop changes and since you want to use both current state and previous state in render, you need to maintain, two different state variables as you are doing

However, when you update the state based on previous state, use functional setState method

Check this answer for more details

[When to use functional setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209452/when-to-use-functional-setstate/48209870#48209870)

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.amount !== this.state.current) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ previous: prevState.current, current: nextProps.amount }));
    }
}
```

According to the latest RFC to React

> **State derived from props/state**
>
> The purpose of this pattern is to calculate some values derived from props for use during render.
>
> Typically `componentWillReceiveProps` is used for this, although if the calculation is fast enough it could just be done in `render`.:

From v16.3.0 onwards, you would make use of

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (
      !prevState ||
      prevState.current !== nextProps.amount
    ) {
      return {
        previous: prevState.current,
        current: nextProps.amount
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2019, check my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225150/4119678). It is not recommended to use `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: @afryingpan your answer is not correct, it is best to use getDerivedStateFromProps

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to update this answer for anyone else who comes here from Google. As of `v16.8.6`, `componentWillReceiveProps` has been marked as legacy, and is not recommended to use. Instead you should use `componentDidUpdate` and update your state based on the new props and previous props/previous state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (this.props.someVal !== prevState.someVal) {
     this.setState({ previous: prevState.someVal, current: this.props.someVal });
   }
}
```

Obviously, whether you check the previous state or the previous props is up to your discretion/situation. You can implement `componentDidUpdate` with or without the parameters, but if you want `prevState` you must declare `prevProps`.

[React Update Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)

[componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an arrow function in your `setState` object. 
Like this :

```js
this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { yourState: prevState.yourState }
    })
```

`prevState` is a default name but you can replace the name as you want