# How to persist state on routing using react-router-dom v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, browser-history

I have two react components let say A and B. When A is shown on the page, user changes something on that page which cause some states changed inside A. Then user click a button which navigate to B by router.push('/b'). Then user click a back a back button and navigate the page to A which is done by router.goBack(). Now the current URL is A but the previously updated states are gone. How can I maintain the state when user go back to A?
without using redux or localstorage as I want to do this with react-router-dom directly.

Comment: Did you. checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130622/react-router-v4-previous-state-component

Comment: Check this one also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466055/how-do-i-pass-state-through-react-router#answer-41499419

Comment: You need to store your state somewhere.

Comment: use useContext hook

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes I have checked this but in this solution they are using localstorage. All I want to know is there some way which i can achive this directly from react-router-dom? l

Comment: you can put it in that way react router state you can do but not recommended as a good way, in the second comment i have posted it has all the ways do check it