# React Filter State Not Rerendering

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I have a handle delete that makes a request to a service.

```
  handleDelete = async studentId => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/students/${studentId}`).then(() =>
        this.setState({
          students: this.state.students.filter(
            student => student._id !== studentId
          ),
        })
      )
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
    }
  }
```

When I commit out the a `axios.delete` and just call `this.setState` it does filter like I want it to.

Why is it that I can't force a rerender of the state with the new data?

Edit: this is my function on the backend to delete.

```
exports.deleteStudent = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Student.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.studentId)
    res.status(204)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `async-await`, you need to resolve the promise. Also make use of `functional setState`.

```
handleDelete = async studentId => {
    try {
        await axios.delete(`/students/${studentId}`)
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          students: prevState.students.filter(
            student => student._id !== studentId
          )
        }))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
    }
  }
```

Check this for more details on [`when to use functional setState`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209452/when-to-use-functional-setstate/48209870#48209870)

Comment: do you get an error or something, can you log state in setState callback

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => ({
          students: prevState.students.filter(
            student => student._id !== studentId
          )
        }), () => console.log(this.state))`

Comment: OK that doesn't return anything. inside the try I did a console.log(this.state):

students [{_id: "5af34c96eb003d0a7476bd0c", name: "", username: "", email: "", notes: "", …}]

Thats a cleaned up version.

Comment: Do you get the `res`, if not just try the edited answer