# ReactJS - prevState in the new useState React hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I really like the new [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and I'm using them frequently for a project I'm working on. I'm coming across a situation where I want to use the *prevState* in the `useState` hook, but I'm not really certain on how to do this.

I've tried something like this, but it fails to compile.

```
const [ someState, setSomeState ] = useState( new Map() )
setSomeState( prevState.someState.set( key, value ) )
```

(by the way, this is to map an array of checkboxes to keep track of the ones that are check marked)

I'm trying to follow this example [here](https://medium.com/@wlodarczyk_j/handling-multiple-checkboxes-in-react-js-337863fd284e), but without using the `setState` function.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to use [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), you'll need to clone it before manipulating the values. Otherwise, it's mutating the original `Map` and React doesn't handle mutatable `state`.

```
const handleChange = useCallback(({ target: { name, checked } }) => {
  setCheckbox(prevState => {
    return new Map(prevState).set(name, checked);
  });
}, []);
```

**Updated Working Example**:

[image: Edit Multi Checkbox Handler]

Comment: Updated answer to include a working `Map` example. While this works, it may be less performant than other alternatives (especially if the `Map` becomes large).

Answer (score 165):

For objects you can use the spread operator to use `prevState` within your `setState` call.

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({
  firstKey: '',
  secondKey: '',
});

setObject((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  secondKey: 'value',
}));

// object = {
//   firstKey: '',
//   secondKey: 'value',
// }
```

The snippet below show an example of using `prevState` for setting the state of an object.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const initialState = {
    firstKey: 'empty',
    secondKey: 'empty',
    thirdKey: 'not empty',
  }
  const [object, setObject] = useState(initialState);
  
  const withPrevState = () => {
    setObject((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      secondKey: 'not empty',
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h5>Updates Second key to 'not empty'</h5>
      <p>First key: {object.firstKey}</p>
      <p>Second key: {object.secondKey}</p>
      <p>Third key: {object.thirdKey}</p>
      <button onClick={withPrevState}>
        Update with prevState
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => {setObject({secondKey: 'not empty'})}}>
        Update without prevState
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => {setObject(initialState)}}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I finally understood how to use this prevstate with this snippet. Thanks

Comment: I believe this decreases performance because React thinks all state entries were set to something new. Additionally, you are cloning an array, which also can cause a dramatic decrease in performance for states with many entries.

Answer (score 18):

`state updater` from `useState` provides a callback pattern which returns you the previous state which you can use to update the current state

```
const [ someState, setSomeState ] = useState( new Map() )
setSomeState(prevState => prevState.set( key, value ) )
```

Comment: Hey I've tried this and I'm getting this error `Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`. Is the `useState` hook limited?

Comment: you might be using `prevState.someState.set( key, value ) ` instead of `prevState.set( key, value ) `

Comment: Reference for the state updater: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: Just to confirm: why using the state from the callback and not `someState`? To avoid messy concurrent updates? I just see this often but never the technical explanation that comes along.

Comment: @EricBurel you don't always need to use functional setState but sometimes it can be really useful. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209452/when-to-use-functional-setstate/48209870#48209870) explains it a some detail for class component but the same applied to functional components too. 

In additional functional state updates with hooks can be really useful to avoid closure issues as well since you are guaranteed to be provided the latest state

Answer (score 9):

You have already the previous state in the destructed variable: `someState`

so you can do:

```
const [ someState, setSomeState ] = useState( new Map() )
setSomeState( someState.set( key, value ) )
```

Comment: Don't know about the OP but this solved a problem I was facing. ThankYou. And smart !

Answer (score 8):

use this

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({thing: 'loading', count: 1});
setSomeState(prev => ({...prev, count: prev.count + 1}));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to update a single value using prevState and useState - You can simply follow this

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0) 
 
if(your-condition) {
  setCount((prevState) => prevState + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [object,setObject] = useState({firstPropertie:'first',
    secondPropertie:'second'})

  setObject(prevState =>
  return{...prevState,secondPropertie:'newValue'})
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [Updating objects and arrays in state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-objects-and-arrays-in-state)

> You can put objects and arrays into state. In React, state is
> considered read-only, so you should replace it rather than mutate your
> existing objects. For example, if you have a form object in state,
> don't mutate it:

```
//  Don't mutate an object in state like this
form.firstName = 'Taylor';

// Instead, replace the whole object by creating a new one: 
// ✅ Replace state with a new object
setForm({
    ...form,
    fistName: 'Taylor'
});
```

Read [updating objects in state](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state) and [updating arrays in state](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) to learn more.