# use PrevState in useState hook in React typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state

I am just trying to figure out how to use `prevState` in the useState hook with React typescript. The button are mapped using the data from the objectData.

So far I have:

```
let data = dataFromFile;

const [chart, setChart] = React.useState<ChartInterface[]>(data);
```

in the component I am doing:

```
export interface ActiveObject {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    cb: (idx: number) => void;
};

export interface ButtonGroupState {
    activeObject: ActiveObject | null;
    objects: ActiveObject[];
};

export interface ButtonGroupProps {
    data: Array<ActiveObject> 
}

   const ObjectData: ActiveObject[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "1 way day",
            cb: () => { setChart(prevState => prevState.set(Data7Day)) }
        },
    ];
```

But that does not really work, any idea's? I get Property 'set' does not exist on type 'ChartInterface[]'. I know thats to do with the interface, but is that the way to do use PrevState in useState and is it needed at all?

Comment: based on `chart`'s type (ChartInterface[]), `chart` is an array. In the `cb` function, you're trying to use `.set` on an array. Add what `cb` should actually do to the question.

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOB No, we return the updated state inside the callback, not call `setState` again.

Comment: Not sure why you are using `.set` at all, doesn't make sense. That's not how React works.

Comment: I have seen .set has been used in other questions as the answer.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823296/reactjs-prevstate-in-the-new-usestate-react-hook

Comment: Like I said, I am unsure on how to use this, thats why I am asking the question - so if its not correct its because I am unsure, this is just an approach i have tried

Comment: @RameshReddy CB function should update state based on previous state. The chart data is an array of objects. I mean the question is do I need to even update state based on previous state for this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
> function to setState. The function will receive the previous value,
> and return an updated value. Here’s an example of a counter component
> that uses both forms of setState:

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

So, basically what that means is that you can also pass a function to the [setter function returned by the useState Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

You need to pass the argument as function, when you need to set the next state, on basis of the current one. As @RameshReddy pointed, if cb function should just change the chart array to a new array called `Data7Day`, you don't need to use a functional state update, you can directly call `setChart(Data7Day)`

for ex...

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

[`setCount(c => c + 1)` is better than `setCount(count + 1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57828519/11667949)

Comment: `setChart(prevChartValue => prevChartValue = Data7Day) / setChart(prevChartValue => prevChartValue = Data1Day)` Would this be right to changing the data state from one to another? Data structure is an array

Comment: You want to replace entire current state (`prevChartValue`) with `Data7Day`(an array), or want to add something to that array ?

Comment: Correct update previous vale of chart to new value which is `Data7Day` this will be from an api ultimately but at the moment is from a hard coded file

Comment: @Sole if cb function should just change the chart array to a new array called `Data7Day`, you don't need to use a functional state update, you can directly call `setChart(Data7Day)`

Comment: @RameshReddy Thanks, thats what I have been asking all along. Can you just explain when prev state would be valid to use? would it only be used for things like counters etc?

Comment: @Sole Whenever the new state depends on the old state you can use the functional update. The state doesn't necessarily have to be counter or anything specific. Go through the linked questions.

Comment: @Sole Now I know what you desire, RameshReddy is right. I have updated the answer accordingly