# React useState hook - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I code useState like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823296/reactjs-prevstate-in-the-new-usestate-react-hook)

```html
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState({
    Search1: "",
    Search2: "",
  });
```

And it throws

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Search1, Search2}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Full code

```html
import * as React from 'react'

const Search = ({ handlerProp, searchQueryProp, inputName }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" name={inputName} onChange={handlerProp} value={searchQueryProp} />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState({
    Search1: "",
    Search2: "",
  });

  function handleEmit({ target: { name, value } }) {
    setSearchQuery((prevState) => ({...prevState, [name]: value}));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search handlerProp={handleEmit} searchQueryProp={searchQuery} inputName="Search1" />
      <Search handlerProp={handleEmit} searchQueryProp={searchQuery} inputName="Search2" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: please also share the component that you use the state in it

Comment: the problem is not with your state definition, you may use the searchQuery object in the JSX syntax which is cause the prolem.

Comment: @novonimo I have add full code at the end of my post. If JSX syntax is the case, so what the fixed?

Comment: your Search component is trying to render searchQuery which is an object. either pass in `searchQueryProp={searchQuery.Search1}` or redefine the logic in your Search component

Comment: change `searchQueryProp={searchQuery}` to `searchQueryProp={searchQuery.Search1} `

Comment: @novonimo 5 minutes to accept an answer

Comment: Thank you Sir, hope the issue was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments before adding the related codes, the problem is with your `searchQuery` object.

##### Why did you get this error?

you passed an **object** instead of a **string** to the `Search` component.
The `input` element, get a `value` property which is a `string`.

##### The solution:

So, change your `App` return section to pass a valid `string` for the `searchQueryProp`:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search handlerProp={handleEmit} searchQueryProp={searchQuery.search1} inputName="Search1" />
      <Search handlerProp={handleEmit} searchQueryProp={searchQuery.search2} inputName="Search2" />
    </div>
);
```

**Note:** always use the lowercase characters to define your variables and constant and only use the uppercase characters in the components name. you defined your state's value with `Search1` and `Search2` which is not correct.