# ReactJS not rendering correct items after splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rendering, splice

So I am attempting to delete an item from an array in React, but after deleting (using splice) item 2 from [1, 2, 3, 4] it re-renders the array to be [1, 2, 3] (at least visually) but when I render one more time (by closing the array and opening it) it renders properly as [1, 3, 4]. Not sure why it's doing this and I think it has to do with splice() but nothing else seems to be working. I tried slice() as well but that didnt work either. Here is the code for my delete function:

```
const deleteFile = (i) => {
        console.log(files);
        const newFiles = [...files];
        console.log('before delete:', newFiles); //prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
        newFiles.splice(i, 1);
        console.log('after delete:', newFiles); //prints [1, 3, 4] but shows visually as [1, 2, 3]
        setFiles(newFiles);
}
```

Comment: A minimum reproducible example will be great, I don't understand what you mean by  "shows visually". Is not clear what is your original input array, your input to the deleteFile function and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

This may be one potential way to achieve the desired objective (ie, remove the element at index `i` in an array named `files`:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
const deleteFile = i => setFiles(prev => prev.filter((f, idx) => idx !== i));
```

> NOTE: Please add index-check (`i` should be `>= 0` and `< files.length`) if needed.

**Explanation**

- `setFiles` may be used with a callback ([click here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502145/13658816))
- `prev` is the existing array `files`
- use `.filter` with `idx` to filter out the element at index `i`

**Code Snippet**

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const deleteItemAt = i => arr.filter((el, idx) => idx !== i);

console.log(deleteItemAt(1));
console.log(deleteItemAt(0));
console.log(deleteItemAt(3));
```