# How does this handleClick function in React retrieve previous state value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010) toggles a button value from `true` to `false`.

I understand this apart from how this `handleClick` function is working:

```
 handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }
```

I am interested in how the function retrieves the `isToggleOn` bool value.

I know we can't directly use `!this.state.isToggleOn` in `setState` - why is the `handleClick` function more reliable in this scenario for a React beginner?

This is where the `handleClick` function is called:

```
render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
```

Comment: If you need to change your state based on the previous state you could use, ```this.setState(prevState...``` ..  ```!prevState.isToggleOn``` will switch the values between true and false on each click ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use functional setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209452/when-to-use-functional-setstate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `setState` docs:

> The first argument is an updater function with the signature:

```
(state, props) => stateChange
```

> `state` is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied.

In your example `prevState` is `state` renamed, and it contains all of the assignments in state, including `isToggleOn`.

You could alternately just read `this.state` in the `setState` function. The `prevState` pattern is used to communicate that this is the old/current state, the state that is being changed.

[setState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can actually use both, because it's really simple and you call the setState from the render function. In class components is a bit hard to find a place where this `this.setState({oldState:this.state.oldState})` can be problematic.
On the contrary, if you use functional components or *hooks*, you can see this problem quite often.

#### JS is not Object oriented!

To understand this you have to think first that js is **not** an object oriented language. React tries just to simulate it. Basically when you change a state, the class containing it gets called again trying to run only the code which changes. In your case, when `handleClick` is called, the `render` function get triggered because the state has changed!

Said this, handleClick is not just a function! It's also a property of the class. React tries to understand whether it should "re-declare" those functions depending on the values they use.

#### Good Practice

In the case you wrote, `isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn`, the function is indipendent. It doesn't need any other property of the class (apart of setState, which works with a different pattern), so after the state changes, the react engine doesn't have to set the function again.

#### Bad Practice (sometimes much much easyer to write)

On the contrary if you use `isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn` the `handleClick` function is dependent of `this.state` so every time it changes, the react engine has to "re-declare" the function by sort of substituting `this.state` with `{isToggleOn:...}`

#### How to recreate that pattern

```js
function myRandom(property){
  //Kind of private Variable
  let hiddenVar=Math.random();
  return property(hiddenVar);
}

//Let's say here the Math class is unreachable while myRandom is.
myRandom((num)=>{
  console.log(num);//This ac
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe just [check the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) on this?

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

In essence, you are getting the previous instance of the state in the function, then making a change to the state and returning it. This new state will get saved and cause a re-render of your component.

If you use functional components, you can negate having to pass a callback  here and could do something like:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [on, setOn] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setOn(!on)}>
      {on? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: I thought we should not use this.state as per React docs [Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: I was not aware of this because I don't use class components anymore and assumed React would handle this. I'll update the answer to reflect that