# What difference between direct argument and callback in setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What difference between direct argument and callback in setState?
I've heard that the react scheduler only correctly exposes component updates when a callback is used. So that they hit the tick 16ms

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(null)

function handle() { 
   setState(true)
   // or
   setState(() => true)
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use functional setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209452/when-to-use-functional-setstate)

Comment: this answer partly no

Answer (score 3):

Using the callback form allows you to use the previous value in state, *even if the previous value hasn't been rendered yet*. For example:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const someHandler = () => {
  setCounter(counter + 1);
  setCounter(counter + 1);
}
```

will only end up increasing `counter` by one, because the `counter` that's in scope when the handler runs is from a single render. It's like doing `setCounter(1); setCounter(1)`, so `counter` ends up being 1, not 2.

Using the callback form allows you to use the previous state:

```
setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
```

will properly increase `counter` by 2, not just 1.

Another difference is that using the callback form allows you to put *functions* into state:

```
const [fn, setFn] = useState();
const fnToPutInState = () => {
  console.log('fn');
};

// ...

setFn(fnToPutInState);
```

will result in the function being invoked immediately, rather than setting state. The solution is to return the function from a callback instead:

```
setFn(() => fnToPutInState);
```

Comment: The callback also allows you to avoid loops when using `useEffect` to update state based on the current value in the state i.e. the dependency array when using the callback is just `[setFn]` where if you were trying to use direct argument you would need `[value, setFn]` to also have access to the current value.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 

I know about batching updates.

I'm interested in more depth, as an example with the work of the react scheduler